# ios swipe tableviewcell to delete sometimes working

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I have a `UIViewController` which has a subview that is a `UITableView`. I want to make it so that the `UITableViewCells` can be deleted by swiping left on the cell and then tapping `Delete`.

However, the swipe is only caught occasionally. It works fine sometimes, but the majority of the time the swipe isn't caught, and the `delete` button does not appear. This is the code I am using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)table editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

// Swipe to delete.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // perform delete logic
    }
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Card *thisCard = self.cards[indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CardCell";
    CardCell *cell = (DCTStripeCardCell *)[DCTBase cellForTableView:tableView reuseID:CellIdentifier indexPath:indexPath];

    BOOL first = indexPath.row == 0;
    BOOL last = indexPath.row == ([self.cards count] - 1);
    BOOL isDefault = thisCard.resourceId == self.customer.defaultCard.resourceId;
    [cell update:thisCard First:first Last:last Default:isDefault];
    if (isDefault) {
        self.selectedCell = cell;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Here is the code I have for `[cell update:First:Last:Default]`

```
- (void)update:(Card *)card First:(BOOL)first Last:(BOOL)last Default:(BOOL)isDefault
{
    [super updateFirst:first Last:last];
    self.last4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CARD ENDING IN: %@", card.last4];
    self.expiration.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"EXPIRES: %@/%@", card.expMonth, card.expYear];
    self.cc_logo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[card getCardImageString]];

    self.defaultCardView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.defaultCardView.layer.cornerRadius = self.defaultCardView.frame.size.height/2.0;
    self.defaultCardView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    if (isDefault) {
        self.defaultCardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
```

I am using `[super update:First:Last]` to round the first and last table cells, since this is no longer supported in ios 7.

Here is the code for that:

```
- (void)updateFirst:(BOOL)first Last:(BOOL)last
{

    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    if (first) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:  (UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }

    // TODO: move common logic to another function.
    if (last) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }

    // This code is probably extraneous
    if (!first && !last) {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath;
        maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners:  (UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)];
        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }
}
```

Not sure what I am missing here. I should note that I am also implementing the `delegate` method `tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

I've tested this on the `simulator` as well as on a `device` so it is not just the simulator that is missing the swipes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any `uigesturerecognizer` added to the viewcontroller?

Comment: nope, no gesture recognizers

Comment: can you show the code of your cellForRowAtIndexPath? Also are you using layoutSubviews method of UITableViewCell?

Comment: @iAmd I added the code in my post. I am not using the layoutSubviews method of UITableViewCell. Perhaps I should note that I am also using `storyboards`.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr you were correct --  had another `uigesturerecognizer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a silly mistake -- didn't realize that this particular `UIViewController` was inheriting from a class that had a `UIGestureRecognizer` already added. To fix this, I simply implemented this function in the parent class:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```